# Input not registering

Tags: c++, file, input

I'm currently working on a library program, specifically deleting a book from a text file. Here is the function in question:

```
void deleteBook(){

ifstream fin;
ofstream fout;

int fileLength = 0;
bool bookExist, looper = false, looper2 = false;
string isbn, author, title, checkOutDate, dueDate, answer, fileLine, isbnCurrent;

while (looper == false){      //Loop to ensure user inputs a valid book

  cout << endl << "Enter the Isbn of the book you would like to delete: ";      //isbn determines book
     cin >> isbn;

  bookExist = isBookExist(isbn);

  if (bookExist == true){
     looper = true;
  }
  else{
     cout << endl << "The book you have entered does not exist in the system, please try again" << endl;
  }
}

getBookInfo(isbn, author, title, checkOutDate, dueDate);    //Retrieves data about book and displays

cout << endl << "The isbn of the book is: " << isbn;
cout << endl << "The author of the book is: " << author;
cout << endl << "The title of the book is: " << title;
cout << endl << "The check out date of the book is: " << checkOutDate;
cout << endl << "The due date of the book is: " << dueDate;

while (true){

cout << endl << "Are you sure you would like to delete this book? (Enter 'yes' or 'no'): ";
  cin >> answer;

  if (cin.fail()){     //This most likely wont come up under any circumstances, but is here for completion
     cout << "Your answer was not valid, please try again." << endl;
  }

  if ((answer.compare("yes") == 0) || (answer.compare("Yes") == 0)){

     fin.open(booksFile);       //open books file and a temporary
     fout.open("tempBook.txt");

     while (getline(fin, fileLine))   //Check how long file is
        fileLength++;

     fin.close();         //reset book file
     fin.open(booksFile);

     while (looper2 == false){

        for (int i = 0; i < fileLength; i += 5){

           getline(fin, isbnCurrent);             //Go through file and look for book in question

           if (isbn == isbnCurrent){

              fout << " " << endl << " " << endl << " " << endl << " " << endl << " ";
              looper = true;    //If book is found, set all fields to empty
              break;

           }

           getline(fin, author);      //If not, continue through file
           getline(fin, title);
           getline(fin, checkOutDate);
           getline(fin, dueDate);

           fout << isbn << endl << title << endl << author << endl << checkOutDate << endl << dueDate << endl;
           //Outputs data back onto file
        }


     fin.close();
     fout.close();

     remove("books.txt");    //sets book file to the temp
     rename("tempBook.txt", "books.txt");
  }
  } else if ((answer.compare("no") == 0) || (answer.compare("No") == 0)){
     break;      //Leave function if user decides not to delete
  }
  else 
     cout << "Input invalid, please enter either 'yes' or 'no' " << endl;
  }
}
```

The program appears to work up until the yes/no section. At which point entering no works as intended, however entering yes does nothing, the program just sits still. I'm not entirely sure where the problem stems from, though the format of the booksFile is as follows:

isbn
title
author
check in date
check out date

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your inner while loop you have:

```
while (looper2 == false) { ... }
```

However, inside that loop you are not setting `lopper2` to `true` (you are setting `lopper` to `true`).

**BTW:** Looking at the way you do your `whiles`, have you thought of using `break` instead of the `looper` variables? For example the first case would be cleaner like this:

```
while (true)
{
    cout << endl << "Enter the Isbn of the book you would like to delete: ";determines book
    cin >> isbn;

    if (isBookExist(isbn))
        break;

    cout << endl << "The book you have entered does not exist in the system, please try again" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks DW! It's been a long day, the little things are catching up with me Wouldn't using a break in a for loop embedded within a while cause the for to terminate and the while to continue?